# Regular curl get request php , why it's very slow?

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm using cURL to make HTTP requests:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "some-site-without-many-photos"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

I need to do this request in loop up to 200 times and get data. I looped for 10 times and it takes more than 25 seconds ... is this normal ? The program is very slow. A few years ago, I did this in C and I remember it's was a lot faster. Any idea make my request faster? Maybe way to get only text from the page?

Comment: you're fetching html. you can't fetch "just the text". You have to fetch all of the html and extract the text you want. If it's slow, then you need to investigate WHY it's slow. Maybe your DNS resolver is borked. Maybe your network link has high packet loss and/or high latency. Maybe the other site is heavily loaded. Until you figure out WHAT the slowdown is, we can't help you.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: user name "warez" and your scraping other peoples sites; desire to help is low

Comment: You could use `curl_multi_*` http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: true @dragon. can you explain what you're planning on doing?

Comment: Many sites are limiting the number of connections from 1 IP within a certain timespan. You are basically DDOSing the server :)

Comment: so tell me please how he doing it?
http://feedbackselector.com/

Answer (score 0):

Start measuring something. You can profile the total request time...

```
$start = gettimeofday(true);
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "some-site-without-many-photos"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
$end = gettimeofday(true);

$request_time = $end - $start;
```

Alternatively, you can just measure the DNS lookup time to see if this is the issue:

```
$start = gettimeofday(true);
gethostbyname("some-site");
$end = gettimeofday(true);

$request_time = $end - $start;
```

Loop this through your 200 or so requests and see the times individually (detects problems with one request), or in aggregate.

If you're requesting pages across different hosts, then you're setting up and tearing down a TCP connection for each request which can take upwards of 500ms depending on your RTT.

Measure and you'll find the issue, although you may or may not be able to do anything about it.

Comment: ok i checked it , dns time is "0.0002..." one request time takes "3.2.." which is very slow - my browser do it faster , i tried on another site and it's much more faster. i try to get data from ebay feedback page, for example
http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=coolhair88&ftab=AllFeedback&myworld=true&rt=nc
any ideas why it's takes 3 second for one request ? and please don't tell me use their api , i need something that their api can't provide

Comment: hi! new information , i try to use fsockopen and it's more faster twice , but no enough , i uploaded the file to free hosting and wow suprise it's 3 times faster! why is that ? and it's can be more fast by changing the code and uploading to faster hosting server?